# Remove clk signal from wave environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, timing-diagrams

How do I remove the clk signal in the wave environment?

[image]

I still want to keep alle the help lines (i.e. the t0, t1, etc.)

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{wavenum}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
% advance clock one cycle, not to be called directly
\newcommand*{\clki}{
  \draw (t_cur) -- ++(0,.3) -- ++(.5,0) -- ++(0,-.6) -- ++(.5,0) -- ++(0,.3)
    node[time] (t_cur) {};
}

\newcommand*{\bitvector}[3]{
  \draw[fill=#3] (t_cur) -- ++( .1, .3) -- ++(#2-.2,0) -- ++(.1, -.3)
                         -- ++(-.1,-.3) -- ++(.2-#2,0) -- cycle;
  \path (t_cur) -- node[anchor=mid] {#1} ++(#2,0) node[time] (t_cur) {};
}

% \known{val}{length}
\newcommand*{\known}[2]{
    \bitvector{#1}{#2}{white}
}

% \unknown{length}
\newcommand*{\unknown}[2][XXX]{
    \bitvector{#1}{#2}{black!20}
}

% \bit{1 or 0}{length}
\newcommand*{\bit}[2]{
  \draw (t_cur) -- ++(0,.6*#1-.3) -- ++(#2,0) -- ++(0,.3-.6*#1)
    node[time] (t_cur) {};
}

% \unknownbit{length}
\newcommand*{\unknownbit}[1]{
  \draw[ultra thick,black!50] (t_cur) -- ++(#1,0) node[time] (t_cur) {};
}

% \nextwave{name}
\newcommand{\nextwave}[1]{
  \path (0,\value{wavenum}) node[left] {#1} node[time] (t_cur) {};
  \addtocounter{wavenum}{-1}
}

% \clk{name}{period}
\newcommand{\clk}[2]{
    \nextwave{#1}
    \FPeval{\res}{(\wavewidth+1)/#2}
    \FPeval{\reshalf}{#2/2}
    \foreach \t in {1,2,...,\res}{
        \bit{\reshalf}{1}
        \bit{\reshalf}{0}
    }
}

% \begin{wave}[clkname]{num_waves}{clock_cycles}
\newenvironment{wave}[3][clk]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[draw=black, yscale=.7,xscale=1]
    \tikzstyle{time}=[coordinate]
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \def\wavewidth{#3}
    \setcounter{wavenum}{0}
    \nextwave{#1}
    \foreach \t in {0,1,...,\wavewidth}{
      \draw[dotted] (t_cur) +(0,.5) node[above] {t$_{\t}$} -- ++(0,.4-#2);
      \clki
    }
}{\end{tikzpicture}}

%%% End of timing.sty


\begin{document}

\begin{wave}{4}{9}
\nextwave{handshake\_out\_RPi}
    \bit{0}{1}
    \bit{1}{2}
    \bit{0}{2}
    \bit{1}{3}
    \bit{0}{2}
\nextwave{data\_out\_RPi}
    \bit{0.5}{1}
    \known{}{2}
    \bit{0.5}{2}
    \known{}{3}
    \bit{0.5}{2}    
\nextwave{handshake\_out\_UR5}
    \bit{0}{2}
    \bit{1}{2}
    \bit{0}{3}
    \bit{1}{2}
    \bit{0}{1}
\end{wave}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to comment `%\bit{\reshalf}{1}` and `%\bit{\reshalf}{0}` in the `clk` definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Delete `clk` in `\newenvironment{wave}[3][clk]`, just the word, leave the brackets empty like `[]` (line 58).
2. Replace `\draw` with `\path` in (line 9).

   `\newcommand*{\clki}{
   \path (t_cur) -- ++(0,.3) -- ++(.5,0) -- ++(0,-.6) -- ++(.5,0) -- ++(0,.3)
   node[time] (t_cur) {};}`

   Previously it said to add `[draw=none]` to `\draw`, corrected thanks to Sigur's suggestion.
3. Comment this bit (line 47-55):

   `\newcommand{\clk}[2]{
       \nextwave{#1}
       \FPeval{\res}{(\wavewidth+1)/#2}
       \FPeval{\reshalf}{#2/2}
       \foreach \t in {1,2,...,\res}{
           \bit{\reshalf}{1}
           \bit{\reshalf}{0}
       }
   }`

[image: figure 1]

Comment: You can use `\path` instead of `\draw[draw=none]` and after, to draw it again, `\path[draw]`.

Comment: @Sigur Awesome :D I'll add that. Thank you.

Comment: @Alenanno thank you! That works perfectly. Now i just have to move the t1, t2, etc. down a bit

Comment: For others: I edited line 66: `\draw[dotted] (t_cur) +(0,.5) node[above] {t$_{\t}$} -- ++(0,.4-#2);` to `\draw[dotted] (t_cur) +(0,-0.5) node[above] {t$_{\t}$} -- ++(0,.4-#2);`

Comment: @NicolaiAntonLynnerup Ah I see you already reached a solution :D

Answer (score 3):

In case [`tikz-timing`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing) could be considered, the desired diagram could be done with something like

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}
handshake\_out\_RPi& 2L 4H 6L 6H 2L\\
data\_out\_RPi & 2Z[black] 4D 4Z[black] 6D 4Z[black]\\
handshake\_out\_UR5 & 4L 4H 6L 4H 2L\\
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\vertlines[help lines]{0,2,...,20}
\foreach \i [count=\col from 0] in {0,2,...,20}
    \node[font=\scriptsize] at (\i,2) {$t_{\col}$};
\end{pgfonlayer}
 \end{tikztimingtable}%
 \end{document}
```

[image]